# Differential equations: Shouldn't the method of separation of variables miss the solutions when x=0?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This question is regarding "Example 6" from the book "Elementary differential equations with boundary value problems" by Edwards and Penney.

Consider the ODE:

$x \frac{d y}{d x}=2 y$    (1)

We apply the separation of variables technique to obtain:

$\frac{1}{y}dy=\frac{2}{x}dx$ (2)

which provides the general solution:

$y(x)=C x^{2}$  (3)

The book mentions that "the general solution (3) satisfies (1) for any value of the constant C and for all values of the variable x".

However, I believe the statement is wrong when $x=0$. By using the separation of variables, we divided by $x$ and $y$ to obtain (2). Thus, we make the implicit assumption that $x \neq 0$, and the separation of variables will generate solutions where $x \neq 0$.

How can $y$ be defined for any $x$, when we implicitly assume that $x \neq 0$?

Comment: And also if $y(1)=0$. So suppose $y(1)\neq 0$. Notice that there exist a $\mathcal C^1$ function that solve, and when you solve your equation, you solve it first in a neighborhood of $1$, i.e. on $(1-\delta ,1+\delta )$ for some $\delta >0$ s.t. $y(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in (1-\delta ,1+\delta )$ (such $\delta $ existe by continuity of $y$). After, the solution may be prolonge over all $\mathbb R$...

Comment: You can check afterwards that the solution really works for all $x$. However, it's not the most general solution, since you could also take $y=C_1 x^2$ for $x \ge 0$ and $y=C_2 x^2$ for $x<0$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ may be different.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, as an *ordinary* DE the domain does not contain the vertical line $x=0$. It is a special feature of this equation that you can take two solutions $=C_1x^2$ for $x<0$ and $=C_2x^2$ for $x>0$ and connect them to a differentiable function at $x=0$. But there is no innate connection between the two constants, one can take any random combination.

Answer (score 1):

For a differential equation of the form $\alpha(x)y'(x)=f(x)(g\circ{y})(x)$ in $y,$ $y$ need not be differentiable at any points such that $\alpha(x)=0$ in order for the equation to be satisfied everywhere else. Hence, the domain of $y$ must initially be assumed to be $\mathbb{R}\setminus{Z}_{\alpha},$ where $Z_{\alpha}:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\alpha(x)=0\},$ and it is only extended to $\mathbb{R}$ if the singularities are removable.

In your example equation, $xy'(x)=2y(x),$ $y$ is assumed implicitly to have domain $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},$ making the domain disconnected. The equation must be separately solved for the cases $x\lt0$ and $x\gt0.$ For the case of $x\lt0,$ there are three further cases to consider: $y\lt0,$ $y=0,$ which is trivial, and $y\gt0.$  For the three cases, one has $$\ln[-y(x)]=2\ln(-x)+C_-$$ $$y(x)=0$$ $$\ln[y(x)]=2\ln(-x)+C_-,$$ respectively. These simplify to $$y(x)=-C_-x^2$$ $$y(x)=0x^2$$ $$y(x)=C_-x^2,$$ which are the cases such that $$y(x)=A_-x^2,\,A_-\lt0$$ $$y(x)=A_-x^2,\,A_-=0$$ $$y(x)=A_-x^2,\,A_-\gt0.$$ The cases can be collapsed into a single case, where $A_-\in\mathbb{R},$ and $y(x)=A_-x^2.$

For $x\gt0,$ the analysis is completely analogous, resulting in the most general solution to be $y(x)=A_+x^2$ where $A_+\in\mathbb{R}.$ Thus, the general solution family for the equation is given by $$y(x)=\begin{cases}A_-x^2&x\lt0\\A_+x^2&x\gt0\end{cases}.$$ Of course, some solutions can be continuously and differentiably extended to $\mathbb{R},$ but this requires that $A_-=A_+=A.$ Such solutions satisfy the differential equation in $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Just to clarify: Consider the particular solution $y(x) = 5 x^2$; is the $[0, \infty]$ largest domain on which it can be defined?

In other words, is there a particular solution that's defined on the whole $R$?

Comment: @AndreiMargeloiu Why do you say $[0,\infty]$ is the largest domain can be defined in? Firstly, $\infty$ is not part of the domain or codomain. Secondly, what you have described is the image of $y$ on $\mathbb{R},$ not the domain. The function $y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},$ $y(x)=5x^2$ satisfies the differential equation everywhere.